# Hiding Scrollview Items from embedded view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

Sorry about the title I didn't know how to say it properly.  I have been playing around with the view controllers within a scrollview concept (like Snapchat) in this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHERMrAcmdo

The problem I'm having is that when I add navigation to the view controllers I want to be able to hide stuff on the scrollview.  I basically added some overlay buttons and I want to hide them when i'm not in those 3 root controllers. There have been a lot of different things I have wanted to change in the scrollview from within the other view controllers but I just don't understand how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you are trying to detect which view the user is on and have some logic that shows and hides some buttons. So if you want your logic to do this within the main ViewController class you could do something like this..

add UIScrollViewDelegate to your ViewController

such as

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate
```

then in the viewDidLoad()

```
scrollView.delegate = self
```

then add this function under the viewDidLoad()

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offSet = self.scrollView.contentOffset
    if offSet.x == 0 {
        print("On scrollview 1") // Hide the button here?
    } else if offSet.x == 414.0 {
        print("On scrollview 2")
    } else if offSet.x == 828.0 {
        print("On scrollview 3")
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I have a table in the view controllers too?  Will that interfere with this?  How will it know whether i'm talking about the table or the big scrollview wrapping the view controllers?  Oh wait, when I declare scrollView.delegate = self do I use the name of the scrollView?

Comment: it says redundant conformance of UsersCollectionViewController to protocol UIScrollViewDelegate.  Can this not be done in a collection view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have figured it out.  This question is also asked somewhere else and I think he ended up doing it a different way but this is the simplest way and probably the best one. The 3 view controllers are childViewControllers of the scrollview, so I had to use self.parentViewController to access the scrollview.